# How to use 2D LiDAR with a constant near object?

Tags: slam, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning to use RPLidar 2 which is a relatively cheap 2D LiDAR for my robot. The problem I have is that the LiDAR will be located at the bottom of the robot and a constant thing behind it is a part of the robot. How can I SLAM with that object being always on sight?

Look at the video example here:
http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam

The guy holds LiDAR, how come his hand does not interfere with laser beams?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310023/how-to-use-2d-lidar-with-a-constant-near-object?/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2018-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can filter out the points which are the robot itself. In your case you can define the minimum and maximum azimuth angle that the LIDAR can see and remove anything outside of that range. You can use the existing [Angle Bounds laser filter](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter) for this.

I'm not sure but it's possible that they were doing something similar in the hetor_slam demo you showed. They were using a Hokuyo LIDAR with a 270 degree FOV so most of the use was probably obscured anyway.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0